# Different Lorentz transformations for classical and quantized Dirac fields?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, spinors, lorentz-symmetry

Under the Lorentz transformation, classical Dirac fields transform like:
$$
\psi(x)\rightarrow\psi^\prime(x^\prime)=\Lambda_{1/2}\psi(\Lambda^{-1}x)
$$
where $\Lambda_{1/2}=e^{-i\omega_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}/2}$ and $\Lambda$ is an element of Lorentz group, while quantum Dirac fields transform like:
$$
\psi(x)\rightarrow U(\Lambda)\psi U^{-1}(\Lambda)=\Lambda_{1/2}^{-1}\psi(\Lambda x)
$$
where $U(\Lambda)$ is a representation of $\Lambda$ in Hilbert space.

In Peskin & Schroesder, *An Introduction to quantum field theory*, page 60, it said when we deal with classical field, "we transformed a pre-existing field distribution that was measured by $\phi(x)$" and when we deal with quantum field "we are transforming the action of $\phi(x)$ in creating or destroying particles". Does it make any difference to these 2 equations? If so, how? I can't see it.

Comment: In the classical theory, the Dirac field is just a spinor-valued function of space-time. In the quantum theory, the Dirac field is an operator-valued function that carries spinor degrees of freedom. In the latter case, the Lorentz transformations can either operate on the spinor degrees of freedom (left-hand side) or they can operate as quantum operators in the Hilbert space in which the Dirac field operator is defined (right-hand side).

Answer (score 2):

In fact, the quantum Dirac field - like every quantum field - transforms *both* in a finite-dimensional representation $\rho_\text{fin}$ of the Lorentz group and in an infinite-dimensional unitary representation $U$ of the Poincaré group, such that
$$ \rho_\text{fin}(\Lambda)\phi(\Lambda^{-1} x + a) = U(\Lambda,a)\phi(x)U(\Lambda,a)^\dagger$$
holds for every Lorentz transformation $\Lambda$ and every translation vector $a\in\mathbb{R}^4$. This property - a sort of compatibility between the classical transformation of the field as a field and the quantum transformation of the field as an operator - is one of the Wightman axioms.

It's not really that the quantum field transforms "differently" from the classical field, it's that it has *two ways* of being transformed. We can apply the classical $\rho_\text{fin}$ to transform the field, but it's now *operator-valued*. And we know from linear algebra that if we let a unitary transformation $U$ act on a vector space as $x\mapsto Ux$, then all operators on the space transform as $O\mapsto UOU^\dagger$. So the second way of transforming the quantum field is an inevitable consequence of us having declared that the quantum field is operator-valued.